# Spring thread safety static utils

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I was wondering if next scenario is thread-safe:
I have a spring controller with method

```
@Autowired
private JobService jobService;
    
public String launch(@ModelAttribute("profile") Profile profile){
    JobParameters jobParams = MyUtils.transform(profile);
    jobService.launch(profile.getJobName(), jobParams);
    return "job";
}
```

and I have `MyUtils` class with static method that transforms one kind of object to another... like so :

```
public class MyUtils {
    public static JobParameters transform(Profile profile) {
        JobParametersBuilder jpb = new JobParametersBuilder();
        jpb.addString("profile.name", profile.getProfileName());
        jpb.addString("profile.number", String.valueOf(profile.getNumber()));
        return jpb.toJobParameters();
    }
}
```

Classes [JobParametersBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParametersBuilder.html) , [JobParameters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParameters.html) and [JobService](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/admin/service/JobService.html)  are from spring batch core project. `Profile` class is simple POJO.

The question really is... is this static method `transform` thread-safe since it is dealing with object instances, although all of those instances are locally created for the method.

Comment: Since your `Profile` class isn't altered elsewhere (by looking at your code) and your static utility method is stateless, it only operates on local variables and arguments, therefore it's thread-safe

Comment: I thought so. But wasn't sure ... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This concrete code IS thread safe if some conditions are met. Here is explanation:

1. `launch` method is called from Spring boot controller. Every call that comes to Spring boot controller is called from different thread and that thread is taking execution to the end of the call stack(unless you call some asynchronous call inside that thread). Tomcat can handle 200 threads in same time by default. Which means you can have 200 calls to your Controllers in same time and they will all be in separate threads. Which means `launch` is thread safe.
2. `Profile` is passed to the `transform` method and if it is simple POJO it is thread safe, because on every call it will be new instance of Profile.
3. Inside `transform` method you are instantiate `JobParametersBuilder` every time which is thread safe if code inside `toJobParameters` is thread safe and doesn't keep any state of the `JobParametersBuilder` class or some other.